# Is there a way to form groups from data in multiple columns in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Take example data, looking at rainfall with temperature readings at two locations:

```
temps <- data.frame(
  rainfall = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
  loc1 = c(77.5, 77.8, 81.2, 82.2, 80.6, 75.9, 77.6, 78.3, 
81.5),
  loc2 = c(79.3, 74.2, 74.9, 77.5, 79.9, 80.1, 82.6, 80.3, 
78.7)
)
```

The goal is to get stats from this data grouped by temperature rounded to the nearest degree. However, we want the data grouped irrespective of location, i.e., for group `80`, this could be a temperature that rounds to 80 at either `loc1` or `loc2`.

Of course, you can perform the groupings and the summarizing on each column independently and then aggregate later, e.g. something along the lines of,

```
lapply(c('loc1', 'loc2'), function(loc) {

  temps %>% group_by(temp = round(!!sym(loc))) %>% 
    summarize(loc,
              mean = mean(rainfall),
              median = median(rainfall)
              )
})
```

This would work for simple arithmetic mean over both `loc1` and `loc2` but not most other stats such as median, standard deviation, etc., because you are left basically with statistics for subsets of data instead of on the whole data of interest.

In other words, the condition we are looking for is "group data by rounded values over all location columns, not just one at a time, such that a given rounded temperature exists in at least one of the columns". So if the temperature rounds to 80 in at least one of `loc1`, `loc2`, this row is included in the group for 80.

I'm looking for a method to achieve this that scales up well for very large data sets.

edit: Here is a crude way to find expected result:

```
temps2 <- temps %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches('loc')), round)

bind_rows(lapply(sort(unique(unlist(temps2[,c('loc1', 'loc2')]))), 
function(deg) {

  temps2 %>% filter(loc1 == deg | loc2 == deg) %>% 
    summarize(deg,
              mean = mean(rainfall),
              median = median(rainfall))
}))

deg     mean median
1  74 1.000000    1.0
2  75 1.000000    1.0
3  76 2.000000    2.0
4  78 2.000000    2.0
5  79 2.000000    2.0
6  80 2.333333    2.0
7  81 1.500000    1.5
8  82 2.500000    2.5
9  83 3.000000    3.0
```

This matches with Calum's answer below.

Comment: This means that groups can therefore be overlapping, correct?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want? Approach is to gather up the loc values, round and then use `distinct` to remove duplicates (so no original row where two loc values rounded to the same group is counted twice). Then we can simply group and summarise as normal. Please provide your expected output so this can be checked!

```r
temps <- data.frame(
  rainfall = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
  loc1 = c(77.5, 77.8, 81.2, 82.2, 80.6, 75.9, 77.6, 78.3, 81.5),
  loc2 = c(79.3, 74.2, 74.9, 77.5, 79.9, 80.1, 82.6, 80.3, 78.7)
)

library(tidyverse)
temps %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>% 
  gather(loc, loc_val, starts_with("loc")) %>%
  mutate(round = round(loc_val)) %>%
  distinct(rainfall, rowid, round) %>%
  group_by(round) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(rainfall), median = median(rainfall))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   round  mean median
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1    74  1       1  
#> 2    75  1       1  
#> 3    76  2       2  
#> 4    78  2       2  
#> 5    79  2       2  
#> 6    80  2.33    2  
#> 7    81  1.5     1.5
#> 8    82  2.5     2.5
#> 9    83  3       3
```

Created on 2018-09-03 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

We can `round` the columns that are 'loc' with `mutate_at`, `gather` into 'long' format, grouped by the 'deg' column `summarise` to get the `mean` and 'median' of 'rainfall'

```
library(tidyverse)
temps %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(matches('loc')), round) %>%
    gather(key, deg, loc1:loc2) %>%
    group_by(deg) %>% 
    summarise(mean = mean(rainfall), median = median(rainfall))
# A tibble: 9 x 3
#    deg  mean median
#  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1    74  1       1  
#2    75  1       1  
#3    76  2       2  
#4    78  2       2  
#5    79  2       2  
#6    80  2.33    2  
#7    81  1.5     1.5
#8    82  2.5     2.5
#9    83  3       3
```

Comment: The one concern here would be that if there is a repeated value in loc1 and loc2 (not in this example), this value is counted twice, so `distinct` must be used as per Calum's answer. (No original row should be counted twice in any grouping.)